# You flip four fair coins

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

You flip four fair coins, if you get 4 heads I will give you $10.00

You pay me $1.00 to play.

Should you play?

I want to have a discussion about the followup from this question, as I believe each play would be independent, but was told no it was conditional...

this means that you can keep playing the game, keeping the number of heads you already got and tossing the remaining coins. Every time you do this, you'll have to pay 1\$ to toss the remaining coins.

Comment: This would be profitable even if you could only flip one coin at a time... you would expect to need two flips per coin, or $8$ flips total, to get all heads, for an expected return of $\$2$. Since you’re allowed to flip more than one coin, the expected payoff must be even greater than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't play since the probability of winning \$10 is $\frac {1} {2^4} = \frac{1}{16}$. So, the expected payout is $\frac{10}{16}<1$ (the cost of playing is 1\$).

---

EDIT: OP mentioned in the comments that you can actually continue playing this game. So, if you get 2 heads and 2 tails for example, you can pay another 1\$ and toss the two remaining coins and keep repeating this process till you get all 4 heads. This makes the problem slightly more interesting. We can now think of the process as a Markov chain with 5 states. Each state represents the number of heads accumulated so far (0 through 4). It is clear that you won't go backwards. If you have 2 heads for example, you can only go to states 2, 3 or 4 if you play again. The complete Markov matrix for this game becomes (some entries left blank for you to fill in)
$$Q=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\frac 1 {16} & . & . & . & \frac{1}{16}\\
0 & \frac{1}{8} & . & . & \frac 1 8\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac 1 2 & \frac 1 4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac 1 2 & \frac 1 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

It is clear that the last state (4 heads) is an absorbing state. If you keep playing, how many times (on average) will you need to pay 1\$ before you reach the absorbing state of 4 heads and collect your 10\$ reward? This is the number of steps within transient states for the Markov matrix. Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) for the fact that the average number of steps needed before getting to the 4\$ absorbing state is the very first entry of the vector:

$$t = (I-Q)^{-1} \Bbb I$$

Here, $I$ is the identity matrix and $\Bbb I$ is a vector of all ones. If this expected number of steps is less than 10, you should certainly play the game.

---

Another less precise and more intuitive way to look at this (if someone stops you on the street and offers you the opportunity and you can't invert matrices in your head) is that the number of remaining coins roughly halves on average every time you play. So, you should need on the order of $\log_2(4)$ tosses until all four coins become heads. This is roughly the amount you'll end up paying and much smaller than the 10\$ reward waiting for you.

Comment: Yes but that's if you consider independent plays, but it is written that they are conditional.

Comment: You mean the coin tosses are not independent? In that case you need to define what exactly the dependence is. Or do you mean you're conditioning on some event happening? In which case you need to define what that event is.

Comment: If the coin tosses are correlated BTW, the conclusion doesn't change.

Comment: I think that the point is that you can turn the coins as many times as you want, leaving the one turned head as head, and paying 1$ to reflip the ones you got as tails, doing this until you get the 4 heads.

Comment: This wasn't clear from your question at all. Edited my answer for this new game.

Comment: Any answer to "Should you play?" that does not take into account risk aversion is problematic. You are answering que question as if the subject should play if and only if the expected value of the lottery is positive. This, however, leads to strange results: see, e.g., [St. Petersburg's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox). According to your reasoning, an individual facing the St. Petesburg Lottery should be willing to pay an infinite entry cost.

Comment: @econbernardo - agree, but only because its framed as "you". What about a hypothetical wealthy gambler who has infinite money and time but still wants to make more? I think they would play this St Petersburg game, wouldn't they?

Comment: Also, if you want to keep things real, then any real casino wouldn't have infinite resources either and when the terms are bounded by the money available on Earth, the expectation argument starts making sense again.

Comment: @RohitPandey See the edit in my answer as a response to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

With the reservations I made in my comment about the question of defining "Should X take this gamble or not" without referencing risk aversion of preferences, below I compute the distribution of this process numerically. I assume the gambler keeps playing until he gets the four heads.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

def gamble():
    '''
    The stochastic process
    '''
    plays = 1
    outcome = -1 # Has to pay 1 to join game
    toss  = np.random.randint(0,2, size = 4) # First toss
    heads = np.sum(toss)
    if heads == 4: # 4 heads
        outcome += 4 # Receives 4
        
    else:
        while not heads == 4: # Keeps playing until he gets 4 heads
            outcome += -1
            plays += 1
            toss = np.random.randint(0,2, size = 4-heads)
            heads += np.sum(toss)
        outcome += 4
    return (outcome, plays)
            
        
        

simulations = [gamble() for i in range(1000000)]
```

Some statistics of the empirical distribution are as follows:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
{} &       money &       plays \\
mean  &        0.49 &        3.51 \\
std   &        1.75 &        1.75 \\
min   &      -20.00 &        1.00 \\
25\%   &        0.00 &        2.00 \\
50\%   &        1.00 &        3.00 \\
75\%   &        2.00 &        4.00 \\
max   &        3.00 &       24.00 \\
\end{array}
[image]
[image]

Again, notice that, even though the mean and median are positive, the distribution of gains is left skewed (empirical skewness is around $-1.33$): you have small probabilities of getting very low results.

An agent who is [risk averse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion) and [loss averse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion) would be specially wary of playing such a gamble. Again, there is no way of answering whether he should play this gamble or not without imposing more structure in the problem (the preferences of the agent).

### Edit: A discussion about choice under uncertainty

Answering  Rohit Pandey's comments:

Yes, a rich person would be more willing to pay a high amount to play the St. Petersburg lottery. As I said, to analyze this better from an individual point of view you would need to impose more structure. There's a whole area in economics called choice under uncertainty who was first developed by [von Neumann and Morgenstern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Morgenstern_utility_theorem) that connects uncertainty to utility. Economists typically assume that individuals are risk averse, and that this risk aversion decreases with wealth (the more wealth someone is, the more risk he is willing to take). This is directly connected to the also common assumption of decreasing marginal utility from wealth: an additional dollar to Elon Musk is of negligible worth, whereas an extra dollar for someone in extreme poverty is worth a lot.

"Also, if you want to keep things real, then any real casino wouldn't have infinite resources either and when the terms are bounded by the money available on Earth, the expectation argument starts making sense again."

The expectation argument does make sense, but for a specific type of risk aversion (risk-neutral utilities). In general, individuals are not risk neutral, but risk averse. This is more of an empirical fact, not a mathematical necessity. Mathematically, risk-neutrality implies an utility that is linear on wealth, while risk-aversion implies an utility concave on wealth. To see why the problem does not disappear by simply considering finite resources, imagine the following gamble: you pay $ \$0$ and win $\$0.01$ with probability $p = \frac{10^6-1}{10^6}$ and lose $\$9,998$ dollars with probability $1-p = \frac{1}{10^6}$. This lottery has positive expected value, but I don't think many people would take it. From a theoretical point of view, this reluctance to accept such a lottery can come, for example, with a concave utility, e.g., $u(w) = \sqrt{w}$. Imagine an individual with an initial wealth $w_0 = 10,000$. The expected utility from taking this lottery $g$ would be:

$$\mathbb{E}(u(g)) = pu(w_0+0.01) + (1-p)u(w_0-9,998) = 99.99 < u(w_0) = 100$$

And such individual would not take that bet.